# What type of connector is this (white, plastic, single or double-row, latching, crimp-pins)?

Tags: identification, connector, wire-terminals

So I am trying to figure out how I can splice 2 or 4 wires together. I know I can do it with these types of connectors. These look like some type of Molex connectors, but I'm not really too sure of the exact classification. I found these on Amazon just by looking up "electrical wire 2 pin 4 pin terminal connectors". They have a pin pitch of 2.8mm and the male housing length is 19mm/0.75in and female housing length is 37mm/1.6inch. They have 2, 3, 4, 6, and 9 pin connectors. I need connectors that are specifically for 14-18 awg wire (I prefer 16 and 14) and also 22 awg wire. I only need 2 pin, 3 pin, and 4 pin connectors. I don't know if the ones shown on Amazon will work. I seen some reviews for the housings or bullet terminals saying they didn't do a good job keeping them in place, crimping the wires, or the wire crimping tool crimped the connectors too much. I'm trying to look up some good quality ones on mouser.com, digi-key.com, or octopart.com, so I need to have an idea of what I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What type of connector is this?

That's a [2.8 mm blade "Automobile" connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=automobile_2p8mm_conn) (my site): Uses 2.8 mm wide quick-connect disconnects. Generic connector found on Chinese sites, no known manufacturer. Based on an obsolete Molex quick-connect boot. Despite its name, it's not an automotive connector."

> I am trying to figure out how I can splice 2 or 4 wires together.

Then you want wire splices, either [permanent splices](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=permanent_wire_splices) or [removable splices](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=removable_wire_splices) (my site).

> I only need 2 pin, 3 pin, and 4 pin connectors.

That's different. Based on your questions, I will make the following assumptions:

- Interior use (as opposed to exterior)
- Removable (as opposed to permanent)
- Multiple connections at once (as opposed to individual terminals)
- Individual wires (as opposed to a cable)
- Wire-to-wire (as opposed to wire-to-board)
- Plugs (as opposed to panel mounted)
- Locking
- Up to 22 AWG wire

If so, I recommend the standard wire-to-wire connector, the [JST SM](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=propr_rect_conn_2p5&s=SM) (my site)

It is [2 to 12 positions, locked, crimp. wire-to-wire, up to 22 AWG wire](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=238).

[image: JST SM]

You can easily buy [ready-crimped JST SM assemblies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HLQ4FX).

[image: JST SM pre-crimped assemblies]

{[source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HLQ4FX)}

Answer (score 4):

From your question, I am assuming that you are looking for a product for a personal project or low-quantity production. For that case, the major problem with most connectors with crimp terminals is the crimping tool. My experience is that unless you use a crimping tool designed for that specific manufacturer and series, the results are often unacceptable. The crimp quality can be rectified by soldering  the wire to the terminal after crimping but this is not recommended; the solder tends to wick up the stranded wiring, making it brittle and nullifying the strain relief properties of the crimp design.

Often, the specific correct hand crimping tool is hard to find or expensive (US$100+).

I had discovered that Digi-Key offers connectors already attached to loose wires.

For example, this search brings up Molex Mini-Fit Jr. 4-position plugs and sockets with wires pre-crumped: [Digi-Key link](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-cable-assemblies/450?s=N4IgjCBcoEwBxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIAzHAOxwBsArCIQCwAML1dbIAuoQAcALlBABlIQCcAlgDsA5iAC%2BhOAmggUkDDgLEyIGGwpg61PoJGRxUuYpUgAnDw1adeQiUjkKjuowsQYVEJGQVlQjBHOEdETTQsD31vEB5eBwBaCFcE3U8DGAo%2BTJY4t0S9L3I4FkcGWNVaugh0hyYNASgwQU7IGAYHOjjpABNRMAnzSxDbcMIhAE8BXFER7BQlJSA).

The first two in the results, as of today: [socket](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/2153211041/12810912) and [plug](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/2153231041/12810790) are pre-crimped with 150mm 16AWG pigtails.

Assuming that you can use the wires supplied in these assemblies, this will solve you having to individually crimp terminals.

Note: My experience is with Digi-Key. I don't know of other supplies of connector-to-pigtail assemblies in individual quantities. There may be other such suppliers of which I am unaware of.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use those because all the wires are black and I need to be able to crimp wires that have different gauge sizes (16, 14, or 22 awg) and colors. I might have to just look for a similar type of product that best fits my needs on Amazon or Ebay, and just hope for the best, hope that the crimp tool that I used doesn't mess up the crimp or connector (i.e. making it too tight/crushed). And yeah, I try to only use Digi-Key and Mouser, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: @rumpled105 The pic you linked looks very much like Molex ones, they have lots of very similar connectors and you likely need a crimping tool (or just outsource the job to some contractor who got it). Is there a reason why you can't use 5mm pitch terminal blocks though? They are much more flexible with different AWG and you can probably use ferrules if you want too, depending on terminal type.

Comment: Generic crimping tools are fairly cheaply available. The connector manufacturer won't honor warranty for anything crimped with third-party tools, yes, but you can also get such third-party tools for like $30 instead of $1000, and if it's for a personal project you're unlikely to be contacting Molex about warranty on a $0.30 connector anyway.

Comment: @Hearth It’s not a question of warranty. It’s a question of making a proper crimp which will (1) make a gas-tight seal between the wire and the terminal, (2) make sure the wire won’t pull out of the crimp, and (3) won’t distort the terminal so much that it won’t fit in the connector. While I don’t have experience with larger connectors like the Mini Fit Jr, I have tried generic crimpers with smaller terminals and have not gotten satisfactory results.